# How to order by the number of relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a "tag cloud" that lists the tag with the most relationships on a many-to-many pivot table schema.

I'm afraid I don't even know what to search in order to begin. I would appreciate any links or code examples, but prefer references so I can learn this once and for all.

I  have a table named companies and a table named categories. There is a pivot table named category_company and the proper relationships are setup and working great.

Comment: I feel like this is best achieved via an SQL query using the query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using `withCount()` should get you there.

```
$companies = Company::withCount('categories');
```

Now you are able to access the count like so.

```
foreach ($companies as $company) {
    $company->categories_count; // gives out the count for this companies categories.
}
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).